# date_format doesn't handle timestamp with `00:00:00`

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datetime, unix-timestamp

It formats `2020-01-27 00:00:00` of type `timestamp` as `2020-01-27 12:00:00` instead of `2020-01-27 00:00:00`

```
  import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
  import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit


scala>   val stamp = typedLit(new Timestamp(1580105949000L))
stamp: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = TIMESTAMP('2020-01-27 00:19:09.0')


scala>   var df_test = Seq(5).toDF("seq").select(
     |     stamp.as("unixtime"),
     |     date_trunc("HOUR", stamp).as("date_trunc"),
     |     date_format(date_trunc("HOUR", stamp), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").as("hour")
     |   )
df_test: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [unixtime: timestamp, date_trunc: timestamp ... 1 more field]


scala> df_test.show
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|           unixtime|         date_trunc|               hour|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-01-27 00:19:09|2020-01-27 00:00:00|2020-01-27 12:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You probably want to use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` as your pattern. (`hh` is for 12h formats, `HH` for 24h)

Comment: @ernest_k Could you please make your comment an answer? It works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

`date_format`, according to [its documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), uses specifiers supported by `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`:

> Converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of string in the format specified by the date format given by the second argument.
>   
> See SimpleDateFormat for valid date and time format patterns.

`SimpleDateFormat`'s documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

`hh` is used for "Hour in am/pm (1-12)". You're looking for the hour in day specifier, which is `HH`.